# Is there a way to detect if macOS screen capturer was called or screenshot was taken?

Tags: javascript, browser

I need to detect if macOS screen capturer was called (`shift+command+4` `shift+command+3`...) or screen capture finished.
Is there a way to do it, in the Browser?

| Demo |
| --- |
| [image] |

Comment: Websites cannot detect screen recording. Apps can detect. If you're using a laptop and watching Netflix on chrome browser and recording it, it cannot detect. But if you download and use the Netflix app from app store, then it can detect and block recording.

Comment: In browser, no.